# Fetching and Printing data from Database in Laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, loops, fetch

Hi I just started working in laravel 8 and I would like to know how to fetch data in database and print data

I have a template of a table with a search bar to see and find user in our database

Here is our controller for the table

**DashboardController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function dashboard()
    {
        $dashboardTitle = "Dashboard";
        $isCurrent = "dashboard";

        return view('dashboard.index', [
            'dashboardTitle' => $dashboardTitle,
            'isCurrent' => $isCurrent
        ]
    );
    }
    public function profile()
    {
        $dashboardTitle = "Profile";
        $isCurrent = "Profile";
        return view('dashboard.profile', [
            'dashboardTitle' => $dashboardTitle,
            'isCurrent' => $isCurrent
        ]
    );
    }
    public function directory()
    {
        $dashboardTitle = "Directory";
        $isCurrent = "Directory";
        return view('dashboard.directory', [
            'dashboardTitle' => $dashboardTitle,
            'isCurrent' => $isCurrent
        ]
    );
    }
    public function journal()
    {
        $dashboardTitle = "Journal";
        $isCurrent = "Journal";
        return view('dashboard.journal', [
            'dashboardTitle' => $dashboardTitle,
            'isCurrent' => $isCurrent
        ]
    );
    }
    public function files()
    {
        $dashboardTitle = "Files";
        $isCurrent = "Files";
        return view('dashboard.files', [
            'dashboardTitle' => $dashboardTitle,
            'isCurrent' => $isCurrent
        ]
    );
    }
}
```

Here is the view

**directory**

```
@extends('dashboard.layouts.dashboard-layout')

@push('css')
      <!-- Custom styles for this page -->
      <link href="{{asset('dashboards/vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
@endpush

@section('content')

          <!-- Page Heading -->
          <h1 class="h3 mb-2 text-gray-800">Tables</h1>
                    <p class="mb-4">DataTables is a third party plugin that is used to generate the demo table below.
                        For more information about DataTables, please visit the <a target="_blank"
                            href="https://datatables.net">official DataTables documentation</a>.</p>

                    <!-- DataTales Example -->
                    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                        <div class="card-header py-3">
                            <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">DataTables Example</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Name</th>
                                            <th>Position</th>
                                            <th>Office</th>
                                            <th>Age</th>
                                            <th>Start date</th>
                                            <th>Salary</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                   
                                    <tbody>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- /.container-fluid -->

            </div>
            <!-- End of Main Content -->
</div>
            <a class="scroll-to-top rounded" href="#page-top">
<i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
</a>
@endsection


@push('script')

    <!-- Page level plugins -->
    <script src="{{asset('dashboards/vendor/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('dashboards/vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js')}}"></script>

    <!-- Page level custom scripts -->
    <script src="{{asset('dashboards/js/demo/datatables-demo.js')}}"></script>
@endpush
```

Our table name is users and I want to print it in the table using a loop

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve all users in your db, you have to :

Dashboard Controller

```
public function directory(){
    $dashboardTitle = "Directory";
    $isCurrent = "Directory";
    $users = User::all();
    return view('dashboard.directory', [
        'dashboardTitle' => $dashboardTitle,
        'isCurrent' => $isCurrent,
        'users' => $users
    ]);
}
```

In Blade

```
@foreach($users as $user)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->postion }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->office }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->age }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->start_date }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->salary }}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Database
Add new rows in database if you haven't (position, office ...)

Controler

```
...
$users = User::all();
return view('dashboard.directory', [
     'users' => $users
        ]
...
```

Blade

```
@foreach($users as $user)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->postion }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->office }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->age }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->start_date }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->salary }}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```